# Expo "yarn androd" command not loading App.js after loading javascript bundle

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

[Please find the screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye1eS.jpg)

I am unable see my app.js code(not exactly code:) UI generated for that code) on the mobile screen after loading the JS bundle. I can only see the blank icon on the center of the screen. Need steps to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution for such errors are

1. shake you device to get the debug options.
   [You'll see these debug options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MkOb.jpg). click on "Reload". You'll see your "App.js" code gets rendered.